# Visual Studio Code TypeScript: Reverse logical expression

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way in VS Code to automatically refactor/reverse a logical TypeScript expression?

Example:

Original:
`!(!foo  || !bar)`

Reversed:
`foo && bar`

Comment: You could try a simple regex search and replace but obviously that won't work for more complex conditions. Maybe you'll write a transformer using the compiler API. Just some ideas for you to try.